# Unable to Error Check / Verfy Condition mysqlPDO PHP Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can't for the life of me figure out why this check when present in a manual mySQL query as TRUE/PRESENT (numrows=1) keeps returning as FALSE (numrows = 0)

```
$sqlPSLocumCheck="SELECT COUNT(assignedRad) FROM rads.nia_sched_master_2017 WHERE ((assignedRad = :locumNarine OR assignedRad = :locumShewchen) AND thedate = :thedate)";
$stmtPSLocumCheck = $dbh->prepare($sqlPSLocumCheck);
$locumNarine=13;
$locumShewchen=14;
$stmtPSLocumCheck->bindParam(':locumNarine', $locumNarine);
$stmtPSLocumCheck->bindParam(':locumShewchen', $locumShewchen);
$numrowsPSLocumCheck = $stmtPSLocumCheck->fetchColumn();
if($numrowsPSLocumCheck>0){
    $psLocumPresent=1;
}else{
    $psLocumPresent=0;
}
echo '<p>'.$sqlPSLocumCheck.'</p>';
```

when I do a manual mySQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(assignedRad) FROM rads.nia_sched_master_2017 WHERE ((assignedRad = 13 OR assignedRad = 14) AND thedate = '2017-09-20')
```

it returns the result that assignedRad 13 is working today

but the $psLocumPresent keeps equaling 0

any help?

Comment: `die(var_dump($numrowsPSLocumCheck);` and tell us what it gives you

Comment: where do you have execute your query?

Comment: so silly! thanks!  i forgot to execute()

Comment: @bobafart It would be nice to accept an answer, since even both of them have told you in detail, were the problem lies. This will help the users, which will read this page in the future, to find their solution based on the one provided for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You Don't have execute your query anywhere so you don't get result. change your code to

```
$sqlPSLocumCheck="SELECT COUNT(assignedRad) FROM rads.nia_sched_master_2017 WHERE ((assignedRad = :locumNarine OR assignedRad = :locumShewchen) AND thedate = :thedate)";
$stmtPSLocumCheck = $dbh->prepare($sqlPSLocumCheck);
$locumNarine=13;
$locumShewchen=14;
$stmtPSLocumCheck->bindParam(':locumNarine', $locumNarine);
$stmtPSLocumCheck->bindParam(':locumShewchen', $locumShewchen);
$stmtPSLocumCheck->execute(); //execute query
$numrowsPSLocumCheck = $stmtPSLocumCheck->fetchColumn();
if($numrowsPSLocumCheck>0){
    $psLocumPresent=1;
}else{
    $psLocumPresent=0;
}
echo '<p>'.$sqlPSLocumCheck.'</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you must set **:thedate** in bindParam because you define it in your query.
also ***B. Desai*** says right you must use of $stmt->execute(); after bindParam

```
       $sqlPSLocumCheck="SELECT COUNT(assignedRad) FROM rads.nia_sched_master_2017 WHERE ((assignedRad = :locumNarine "
               . "                      OR assignedRad = :locumShewchen) AND thedate = :thedate)";
                                        $stmtPSLocumCheck = $dbh->prepare($sqlPSLocumCheck);
                                        $locumNarine=13;
                                        $locumShewchen=14;
                                        $stmtPSLocumCheck->bindParam(':locumNarine', $locumNarine);
                                        $stmtPSLocumCheck->bindParam(':locumShewchen', $locumShewchen);
                                        $stmtPSLocumCheck->bindParam(':thedate', $thedate);///you must set this variable because you define it in your query
                                        $numrowsPSLocumCheck = 
$stmtPSLocumCheck->execute(); //execute query
$stmtPSLocumCheck->fetchColumn();

                                        if($numrowsPSLocumCheck>0){
                                            $psLocumPresent=1;
                                        }else{
                                            $psLocumPresent=0;
                                        }
                                        echo '<p>'.$sqlPSLocumCheck.'</p>';
```